# systemVerilog signed doesn't work correctly

Tags: system-verilog, signed

I have the following function:

```
   function tx_upconv_out_transaction predict(tx_upconv_in_transaction in_trx);
      tx_upconv_out_transaction predicted = tx_upconv_out_transaction::type_id::create("predicted");
      //-------golden model-----
//      predicted.y = (in_trx.xi * in_trx.cos - in_trx.xq * in_trx.sin)/ (2 ** 17);
      $display(" xi = %d, cos = %d xq = %d sin = %d", $signed(in_trx.xi),$signed(in_trx.cos),$signed(in_trx.xq),$signed(in_trx.sin) );
      predicted.y = ($signed(in_trx.xi) * $signed(in_trx.cos) - $signed(in_trx.xq) * $signed(in_trx.sin))/ (131072);      
      return predicted;
   endfunction: predict
```

Where:
The field in in_trx are defined by:

```
   bit [15:0]  xi;
   bit [15:0]  xq;
   bit [15:0]  sin;
   bit [15:0]  cos;
```

For the input:

```
xi, qq = fffa (hex)
sin = 0
cos = 7ffe (hex)
```

The output (display) is:

```
xi =     -6, cos =  32766 xq =     -6 sin =      0
```

Where it should be:

```
 xi =     -6, cos =  -2 xq =     -6 sin =      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your vectors to signed and unsigned (default). Eg.:

```
logic signed [3:0] signed_reg; // a 4-bit vector in range -8 to 7
```

From now you you will not need `$signed` systemcalls.
Also if you are using 16 bit 2-state variables you should consider the built in 
`shortint` type that is a *2-state data type, 16-bit signed integer*.

Comment: The signed decimal value of 16'h7ffe is 32677, not -2. So it is working correctly.